# Google Analytics - Enforce Screen Tracking

Tags: java, android, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Good evening. I am using Google Analytics v3 in my Android app. I want to simulate screen views in my MainActivity. How can I enforce a screen view?

Using EasyTracker it's not working as follows:

```
// track one screen
easyTracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "First Screen"); 
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());

// track another screen
easyTracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "Second Screen"); 
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
```

It just tracks the first screen but not the second. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about google analytics but you may try Flurry analytics tools

Comment: I already knew Flurry, but gave it the first try now and it seems to fit my needs perfectly! Thank you for your input